# How to correct wrong task bar icon for windows explorer.exe?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

The windows explorer.exe program's task bar icon is mixed up with some other program, how can I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Taskbar properties change the size of icons to the oposite (if "small" in "Use small icons" then change it to "not small"), apply the change, revert to the previous state and ... that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You may also try to clear/rebuild the Icon Cache.

Close and save everything you got open.

1. Open Taskmanager
2. Find and stop the `Explorer.exe` process
3. In Taskmanager click the Tab Applications and start a new Process `CMD.exe`
4. In command line enter: `CD /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local`
5. Still in command line: `DEL IconCache.db /a` and afterwards `Exit`
6. In Taskmanger click again on the button to start a new process and start `Explorer.exe` again.

When done reboot your machine.

Comment: Hi, I just tried these steps. But It still doesn't work. Problem persists.

Comment: Can you pleace try to create a new User Account on the PC with the Icon problem and check if for him the icons are still wrong?

Comment: Hi ap0, my laptop belongs to my company. I don't have authorization to create a new account.

Comment: I see. Well it could be possible that your user profile is corrupted and createing a new one would help. Unfortunatly those two things are the only solution I had in mind. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
Start ► Control Panel ► Personalisation ► Window Colour ► Advanced Appearance Settings► Item ► In the drop down list select Icon ► The default size for all icons is 32.

Comment: **Advanced Appearance Settings** is not an option here (Windows 7). In any case changing icon size will not fix the OP's problem.

Comment: So, what about this?
http://i.stack.imgur.com/0ageR.jpg

Comment: I see a window likw [this](http://winsupersite.com/site-files/winsupersite.com/files/archive/winsupersite.com/content/content/128595/win7/win7_rtm_homepremium_06.jpg). When I click on "Window "Color" I see a window like [this](http://gilsmethod.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/images/change-windows7-fonts-2.jpg) with no Advanced settings ...

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate Edition. May be you have a lower Edition of Windows

Comment: Home Premium ...